# How to handle RESTful response of Entity with self-reference

Tags: java, json, rest, jpa, jackson

I have a class Foo which have reference to itself.
This is rough example of situation I have been in.

```
@Entity
public class Foo() {
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_Foo")
  private Foo parent;
}
```

When i pass Foo object to JSON response generator, all required getters are initiated and all required data retrieved from DB by JPA.

Now the problem is that if i remove @JsonIgnore from self-reference field I'm getting parent info, and parent parent info and etc.

What I want is that I could limit deep of retrieved parent info.
For example.:

- Deep 0 - I will get only Foo data
- Deep 1 - I will get data of Foo and Foo parent
- Deep 2 - I will get data of Foo and Foo parent and Foo parent parent
  etc.

Maybe there is a simple solution with annotations or smth, because i couldn't find anything.

**EDIT:**

Solved this problem with custom serializer and some recursion magic.

```
private void serializeParents(JsonGenerator gen, Foo value, int currentDepth) {
    if (currentDepth < PARENTS_DEPTH) {
      if (value.getMom() != null) {
        serializeParentData(gen, value.getMom(), currentDepth);
      }

      if (value.getDad() != null) {
        serializeParentData(gen, value.getDad(), currentDepth);
      }
    }
}

private void serializeParentData(JsonGenerator gen, Foo value, int currentDepth) {
    gen.writeObjectFieldStart(Gender.M.equals(value.getGender()) ? "dad" : "mom");
    // other parameters ...
    serializeParents(gen, value, currentDepth + 1);
    gen.writeEndObject();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to create a custom DTO object to gather all your `Foo` properties as well as its `parent`, so you won't get a recursion relationship and avoid lazy loading exceptions.

So you will keep your entity as it is:

```
@Entity
public class Foo() {
   @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
   private Long id;

   @JsonIgnore
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "id_Foo")
   private Foo parent;
}
```

And create a custom DTO object like this:

```
public class FooDto() {

   private Long id;
   private Foo parent;

   //getters and setters here
}
```

Then you can use this DTO to store JSOn results in your requests.

You can take a look at [**What is the point of using DTO (Data Transfer Objects)?**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171457/what-is-the-point-of-using-dto-data-transfer-objects) for further details.

**`@JsonIgnore` documentation:**

According to the Jackson [**`@JsonIgnore` documentation**](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) there's no such option(property) to specify a depth/level for the annotation, as there's only one possible property `value` to define if this anotation is active or not.

Comment: I was thinking about something like that but though there is more simpler (already implemented and easier to use) way. Thanks for your answer, i will mark it as solution to my question, because it really is.

Comment: You are welcome, Yes there's no solution using annotations, as far as I know, so this will be the best way to do it.

Comment: @Karolis How did you make this work? I have similar problem with my Spring Boot Application. Could you help?

Comment: @Yash I know I'm so late, but I edited my question. Maybe others will find it useful.