# How to get record up to n level in Hibernate self join

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class as:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="EMPL_MSTR_CUR_V1")
    public class EmployeeMasterVO {
        private String emplId;
        private String name; 

        private String supervisorId;
        private EmployeeMasterVO supervisor;

        /**
         * @return the emplId
         */
        @Id
        @Column(name="emplid") 
        public String getEmplId() {
            return emplId;
        }
        /**
         * @param emplId the emplId to set
         */
        public void setEmplId(String emplId) {
            this.emplId = emplId;
        }
        /**
         * @return the name
         */
        @Column(name="name")
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param supervisorId
         */
        public void setSupervisorId(String supervisorId) {
            this.supervisorId = supervisorId;
        }

/**
     * 
     * @return String
     */
    @Column(name="SUPERVISOR_ID")
    public String getSupervisorId() {
        return supervisorId;
    }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn( name = "SUPERVISOR_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=true)
        @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
        public EmployeeMasterVO getSupervisor() {
            return supervisor;
        }
        public void setSupervisor(EmployeeMasterVO supervisor) {
            this.supervisor = supervisor;
        }

        //emplStatus - getter & setter
       // employeeGroup -getter & setter
    }
```

and having the criteria query as:

```
 Criteria cri = getSPGSession().createCriteria(EmployeeMasterVO.class, "employeeMasterVO")
                    .createAlias("employeeMasterVO.supervisor", "supervisor",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
            cri.add(Restrictions.eq("employeeMasterVO.emplStatus", "3"));
            cri.add(Restrictions.ne("employeeMasterVO.employeeGroup", "C").ignoreCase());

empldtls = cri.list();
```

Getting result as expected 
but when I  do `empldtls.get(0).getSupervisor()` it again contain supervisor and so on..

So my question is how can I limit up to 2 level only means
if I do  `empldtls.get(0).getSupervisor()` I should get supervisor dtails but
when I do `empldtls.get(0).getSupervisor().getSupervisor()` I don't need this level. What shuld I do, any help is appriciated.

Comment: you cant do that, anyway it is Lazy loaded so entity will not be loaded until someone try to access its data.

Comment: You may take a look at [**this similar question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811471/how-to-handle-restful-response-of-entity-with-self-reference/42812724#42812724), afaik there's no depth/level solution.

Comment: @hunter Yes it's lazy loaded when I do empldtls = cri.list() I can see multiple log for getting supervisor until supervisor id is not found

Comment: Can you explain what problem you're having in a little more detail. As it stands this makes little sense.